# Ubuntu 12.04 - Howto downgrade vsftpd?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, downgrade

How can I downgrade `vsftpd` from the latest Ubuntu package (2.3.5) to version 2.3.2?

I have tried to put this into `/etc/apt/preferences` file:

```
Package: vsftpd
Pin: version 2.3.2*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

However, every time I do `sudo apt-get install vsftpd` it installs version 2.3.5: `vsftpd_2.3.5-1ubuntu2_i386.deb`

Is there something else I need to do or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are after is not *pinning*, but *holding*.

Holding a package can be achieved with

```
  echo vsftpd hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

See [Ubuntu Pinning Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction_to_Holding_Packages)

**Edit:** as for the original question it would probably be easiest to uninstall whatever version is there and download the version you need from [Ubuntu Main pool](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main) and install it with `dpkg -i`. Afterwards hold to it as describe above.

Comment: Hmm I tried holding, but no luck. I think it is because I already had 2.3.5 installed (as it is the latest version in Ubuntu 12.04). I also tried removing vsftpd and then installing it again, but unfortunately it keeps installing 2.3.5. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It would probably be easiest to download the package from [pool](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vsftpd/vsftpd_2.3.2-3ubuntu5.1_i386.deb) and install it with `dpkg -i vsftpd_2.3.2-3ubuntu5.1_i386.deb`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "needs read/write" access errors when running the hold command, even with "sudo".  It did finally work when I switched to root (sudo su) and ran it as root.  Just in case anyone else has the same issue.